# Rails 3: Serving static assets from different locations depending on theme

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, assets, rails-engines

I'm creating a simple theme system for a rails 3 application.
A theme consists of a folder placed in `Rails.root`/themes containing

- A .yml manifest file
- some [liquid](http://www.liquidmarkup.org/) template files
- A static assets subfolder

Now for certain controller/action i would like to render views from the current theme, and so using static assets accordingly.

Hence i need a way to tell rails to rewrite

- `http://example.com/theme1/*    ---->   #{Rails.root}/themes/theme1/assets/*`
- `http://example.com/theme2/*    ---->   #{Rails.root}/themes/theme2/assets/*`
- ...

Currently i can't figure out how to do this since i would like avoid both using a different engine for every theme or copying assets files in a subfolder of `public`.

How can i solve this problem?

**edit: other requirements**

I was looking for something that does not upset the rails defaults, this way later I could take advantage of the new asset pipeline feature (planned for rails 3.1).

Currently I found only this:

```
config.asset_path = proc { |asset_path| "assets/#{asset_path}" }
```

that would have fully met my requirements, unfortunately it will not apply when assets pipeline is enabled.

Comment: Good question, let me know if you figure this out. I'm very interested in the idea of being able to have simple theming that can be on a per-object basis.

Comment: Quick question about something I'm not clear on, are you showing assets from one theme on a page at a time, or can a page contain assets from multiple themes at once?

Comment: @SaucyK: i'm showing assets from one theme on the same page, but is not required: if someone knows the urls of multiple themes assets is not prevented to use them (and i really can't prevent them to do so).
Currently i've some helper methods to embed assets from the current theme.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [themes_for_rails](https://github.com/lucasefe/themes_for_rails) plugin.

The following excerpts from the readme shows how you can change the theme used based on any logic you require.

In a controller action:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def show
    theme "purple"
  end
end
```

At a class level in your controller:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  theme "purple" # all actions will use this theme
  def show
    ...
  end
end
```

Or using a "resolver" lambda/function:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  theme :theme_resolver
  # ...
private
  def theme_resolver
    current_user.theme # or anything else that return a string. 
  end
end
```

There are also helper functions for your views and mailers.

Comment: Already looked at it, i was only intrested on how it deals with static assets since i don't want erb or haml ecc.. (maybe i could come across this overriding `render` function?). themes_for_rails does all the work itself: it has an `AssetsController` that is responsible for serving assets and it uses the 'send' function to accomplish this.

Comment: This solves my problem, but i was looking for something less `handwritten` and more robust such some rack middleware, or just a rails configuration option in order to take the advantage of the new [asset pipeline feature](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) planned in rails 3.1. 
I found only this: 
`config.asset_path = proc { |asset_path| "assets/#{asset_path}" }`
that would have fully met my requirements, unfortunately it will not apply when assets pipeline is enabled.